# how to make .exe from nodejs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, babeljs, exe

Im trying to make .exe from my nodejs project. I'm using the pkg command but when I type `pkg package.json` in cmd, i get this message

```
> pkg@5.8.0
    > Warning Babel parse has failed: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: "importAssertions". (1:39)
> Warning Cannot include directory %1 into executable.
  The directory must be distributed with executable as %2.
  %1: node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium
  %2: path-to-executable/puppeteer
> Warning Cannot include directory %1 into executable.
  The directory must be distributed with executable as %2.
  %1: node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium
  %2: path-to-executable/puppeteer
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node10-x64 for file`
```

I am importing the JSON file with the following:

```
import config from "../../config.json" assert {type: "json"}
```

Here is my package.json: [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yimf.png)

Am I importing config.json the wrong way?
Am I packaging my app the wrong way?
Am I doing the wrong way to make .exe ?

Comment: So... why not just enabling the parser plugin import assertions, as the warning instructs? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions

Comment: Thats what id like to do but i cannot find how.

Comment: did you install the module using npm and add it as a dev dependancy?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll make an answer so I can edit it and be more thorough than a comment, though I can't be sure that this is the full solution, this is definitely part of it.

You need to install the importAssertions Babel plugin.

You can do that by running this line in the cmd line:

`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions`

Also, be aware that the syntax `import config from "../../config.json" assert {type: "json"}` is [experimental](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions), and is not yet part of the actual standard. That's why you need to install the plugin to use it. Instead of what you are doing, what I would reccomend is simply modifying config.json to be config.js and making the js file:

```
module.exports = {
    //whatever json was originally in the config file
}
```

This would mean you would no longer need the experimental syntax and, unless it's actually important the config file be a straight json file, it would be easier. It also means you won't have to fix things if/when that experimental syntax changes slightly.

Comment: I did made the json an module.export. Now the message has changed : the     `> Warning Babel parse has failed: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: "importAssertions". (1:39)` has been deleted but the rest is still there.

Comment: @Timen is it generating a .exe at all? Because the other two warnings are just saying you need to include certain folders,which shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @TImen try out this thread, they appear to be struggling with the same problem. https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/721

Comment: Ok, i found the problem, he wants to have "puppeteer" folder at the same path that the executable. So i putted puppeteer outside "node_modules" but now i dont understand how i should import puppeteer. I get this `Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import 'my_path\codeSource\puppeteer' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from my_path\codeSource\src\service\launchPup.js`

Comment: And no, ,it doesnt create executable at all.

Comment: @Timen put it both outside and inside. Put a duplicate of the folder from node_modules in the build folder, but don't remove it from node_modules.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: @Timen sorry, at this point I really have no idea.

Comment: Thank you, my mentor going pas to holiday in a few days, thanks to have tried.